# Huawei 8.0 Renderscript failed loading RS driver

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera2, renderscript, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing an app that uses the **Camera2 API** and the **Renderscript API** to perform YUV to RGB conversion using a custom script.

The app is working on every device but on high end **Huawei** devices with **Android Oreo 8.0** (7.0 worked just fine).

My doubt is that in the new update a library is missing and that the default RS implementation can't handle my operations.

Here is the logcat related to RS when the app is started:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService() returned 0x0
    Using Fallback Path.
E/RenderScript: Failed loading RS driver: dlopen failed: library "libRSDriverArm.so" not found
E/RenderScript: Failed to load runtime libRSDriverArm.so, loading default
D/RenderScript: Successfully queried cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache
    Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/librs.yuv420888.so): (null)
V/RenderScript: Invoking /system/bin/bcc with args '/system/bin/bcc -unroll-runtime -scalarize-load-store -rs-global-info -rs-global-info-skip-constant -o yuv420888 -output_path /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache -bclib /system/lib/libclcore_neon.bc -mtriple armv7-none-linux-gnueabi -O 3 -fPIC -embedRSInfo /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/yuv420888.bc -build-checksum abadcafe'
V/RenderScript: Invoking /system/bin/ld.mc with args '/system/bin/ld.mc -shared -nostdlib /system/lib/libcompiler_rt.so -mtriple=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi --library-path=/system/vendor/lib --library-path=/system/lib -lRSDriver -lm -lc /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/yuv420888.o -o /data/user_de/0/com.loopsie.android/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/librs.yuv420888.so'
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
```

Following the flow of the app, the frame is sent from the Renderscript allocation to the Surface of a SurfaceTexture connected to OpenGL.

It seems that the frame is received but due to some internal error it's all black.
Since the same app worked on 7.0, my concerns are on the 8.0 update.

Is there a way to investigate further this issue?
As anyone more insight to provide?

Comment: I am running into the same issue on the Huawei P20 lite. Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: If my answer helped then mark it the correct answer so other people with the same problem can actually see it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a runtime error of RS library caused by an update which leads to incompatibility with certain devices. Try either downgrading your gradle version to:

```
>  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Hope this helps.

**However**, it should be noted that the documentation says it caches a device specific *optimized* version of your script, keyword 'optimized'. This means that your script should still work on devices where this error pops up (including your Huawei).

**UPDATE** Try using:

```
gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

// buildToolsVersion does NOT have to be manually set as you are using gradle version > 3.2.1 (will default to 28.0.3) so you can remove this line.
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

I believe this patch solves your problem on your phone as well. If not, you can still go with the 3.2.1 solution.